# WSL2 With Tensorflow 2.16 dosent detect my gpu in PyCharm but does in console

Tags: tensorflow

WSL2 With Tensorflow 2.16 dosent detect my gpu in PyCharm but does in console.. essentially what the title said.

Console output

[image]

While when I try to use the same env in pycharm I get:
[image]

I am stuck and don't know where to go from here..

Comment: Was unable to resolve it... rewrote my models to pytorch works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Things you try checking:

- check if you are using the same environment in both cases.
- Try reinstalling tensorflow using `pip install "tensorflow[+cuda]"` as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

To get better help, try posting more details like Versions instead of screenshots.Other may downvote the post because of the low details of the post. Please check at stackoverflow, similar posts are already mentioned over there